# How does applying as the owner of a one-month old company stand up in a Schengen business visa application?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, business-travel, algerian-citizens

I'm applying for a business visa to be able to find people that I can outsource work to, as well as to buy some equipment that I need for my company. I own the LLC with 2 other people and I work as CEO. The company is only 1 month old and we need to get our stuff ASAP from Poland or the Czech Republic.

Will the fact that my company was only established a month ago affect my ability to get a business related visa? I'm Algerian applying from Algeria.

Comment: I think the tag visa-refusals is not really right here. That is mostly used to cover questions on what to do after having been refused while yours looks like the fear of going to be refused or what to do to avoid to being refused.

Comment: I think it's logical to use it when targeting people who have an experience with visa-refusals

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply for a regular visitor visa, not a business visa. A business visa is one where you are invited by a business already established in host country.

Here are the **additional** requirements for a business visa to Poland (from the Polish embassy in Kuwait, but the requirements are the same no matter where you apply from as they are for the Schengen visa scheme):

> Business visa – additional documents
>
> 1. Invitation from inviting person or institution, stating the purpose and conditions of visit (period of stay, who covers expenses
>      etc.), on a head letter paper, signed by an authorized person;
>
> Invitation letter from company/authority in Poland/Schengen Area with
>   full address, stating the purpose and duration of the business trip
>   and/or
>
> Information on event/congress/trade fair, i.e. information about
>   organizer/host incl. full address in Poland/represented Schengen
>   country, duration of event and purpose of participation (e.g.
>   con-firmed congress participation, trade fair visitor’s ticket or
>   exhibitor’s ticket, confirmation proof of trade fair exhibitor) and/or
>
> Information reflecting the existence of trade relations or relations
>   for work purposes stating de-tails of company in Poland/represented
>   Schengen country and Kuwait.
>
> 2. Documents regarding applicant’s sufficient means of subsistence during intended stay, such as: letter from employer with employer’s
>      consent for travel; salary certificate; personal/business bank account
>      statements; proof of income generated by property; letter from sponsor

If you are unable to supply the above, your application may be rejected simply on the basis that you applied for a visa, but your documents do not support that visa type.

I would suggest applying for a normal tourist visa (there are no restrictions on purchasing goods or conducting interviews / hiring people on a tourist visa).

Comment: There's no such thing as separate business or tourist visas in the Schengen rules.

Comment: @HenningMakholm there isn't, but there are different requirements depending on your purpose of visit

Comment: @JonathanReez: The overall requrements are always the same, namely that you present evidence that convinces the consulate of the purpose and conditions of the intended stay. Lists such as the ones quoted in this answer are generally not hard requirements but explicitly _non-exhaustive lists_ of documents that will often be useful for lifting that burden. In particular they do not mean that the purpose of stay _must_ be one where exactly the enumerated documents would be expected to exist.

Comment: My understanding is that there are two (main) kinds of visas, C and D for short and long term visits. However, in many parts of the world the _terminology used_ makes it easier for the lay person to understand what may be required given the purpose of their visit. The quoted section is lifted directly from the polish embassy in Kuwait's website; so clearly if they are using that terminology, it would be okay to use it in an answer to the question.